# Chrome tab hierarchy

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

Is there a way to get some sort of indication which tabs were spawned from a certain window.

sort of like [this Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/)

or like the way the tabs are coloured in the latest IE

Thanks

Comment: I've made a feature request regarding adding such a feature to Chrome, so it would be available from the box. In case anybody is interested, join discussion here:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344870

Comment: @Nathaniel, How does this work? What do you mean by "coloured"?

Comment: If i remember correctly, I was talking about the feature in IE9 where when you spawn new tabs off an existing tab, IE will colour the original tab and any offspring tabs a certain colour. As an example, i open a tab and search fdsa on google, then from that tab, I open two links, all three tabs are coloured blue. If i then create a new tab, do a google image search, open the first link, the second two tabs are coloured pink http://imgur.com/F85bwGm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) is the best. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to [TooManyTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp/related) for chrome. It shows the opened tab in the thumbnail view. Also like FF their is the same addon for Chrome is available [Tree Style Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ffididlaalcoegfcalmeldjfnihmoech/related) which is in **beta** state so many bugs will be. You can also give a try to [IE Tab Multi (Enhance)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea) which gives the experience of IE on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for little details, have not tested them properly yet. for now i use first one.

- [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl)
- [Sideways Tree Style Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/biiammgklaefagjclmnlialkmaemifgo)
- [Tab-Sidebar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/egmcoemabahnkbkfgdifiafkhebcfpfo)

Will update after fiddling around with them